# Text show in imageview using glide

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent

In my text I want to show first word in imageview.I will try many time with glide.But it did not work in adapter.Now how can I solved it?

```
                String name = "Masum";
                Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(name)
                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .into(holder.nameView);
```

Comment: Do you want to place Text above ImageVIew?

Comment: just set a text as like image

Comment: ImageView is not designed to show text (obviously). Use TextView to show text

Comment: Glide.load(string) is to load a file name, not paint a string on the image view.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment.I will try it.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2017/02/android-creating-gmail-like-inbox-using-recyclerview/

Comment: Simply you  **can not** do this with `Glide.`

Comment: You are confusing yourself `Glide` library is for loading images into `ImageView` this library will fetch the image decode bounds and will scale to fit as per the `ImageView` dimensions and then cache image on disk/memory or as specified. How can an Image caching library work with text ? Both are totally different things image and text.

Comment: Use a custom layout with both `TextView` and `ImageView` and use `Glide` for image and `TextView` for text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drawableleft property of textview. And try to set it programatically.

Comment: sorry this will not give proper solution